# url_for adding controller and action to querystring in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, actionmailer

I am trying to generate a url in an actionmailer template. An example if the url I want to generate is

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/users/confirm/lNbQxzFukYtEEw2RMCA
```

Where the last segment is a hash to identify the user

However when I use this

```
<%= url_for(:controller => 'users', :action => 'confirm', :id => @user.confirmhash, :only_path => false) %>
```

It generates this

```
http://0.0.0.0:3000/assets?action=confirm&controller=users&id=ZOR3dNMls8533T8hJUfCJw
```

How can I get it to correctly format? I have no idea where 'assets' is coming from.

Is there an easier way to use named routes that I am missing?

Comment: Is confirmhash a field in the table, or a method in the model. If method, please share so that we can analyze further. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer. As I'm still learning I've missed the option to create a named route. So this this the path I've taken.

In config/routes.rb

```
match 'user/confirm/:id' => 'users#confirm', :as => :confirm_account
```

Then in my action mailer template I've used

```
<%= link_to "Confirm your account", confirm_account_url(@user.confirmhash) %>
```

Which passes the :id into the controller action.